# Desabilitar validação nativo do navegador

Tags: jquery, html, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria de saber como desabilitar a validação nativa do navegador em um formulario? Gostaria de deixar apenas minha validação em JQuery.

O que eu queria tirar é essa caixa de texto "Preencha este campo.".

Alguma sugestão? Tentei usar novalidate, mas ele ignorar até minha validação em JQuery.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adiciona o atributo [`novalidate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-novalidate) à `<form>`.

Esse atributo é exatamente para dizer ao browser que a form não deve usar validação do HTML5.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u0ts0w8k/1/

Se puderes coloca o atributo logo no HTML, senão podes fazer com JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('novalidate', true);
```

Comment: E usei esse atributo, e funcionou. Mas o problema é que ele ignora minha validação em JQuery também... Quero que minha validação em JQuery continue a funcionar.

Comment: @Vynstus qual é a validação que estás a usar? podes colocar um exemplo do código? Podes adaptar o meu jsFiddel talvez para mostrar um exemplo do problema.

Comment: De uma olhada, mesmo com a validação jquery, ele executa o submit. https://jsfiddle.net/u0ts0w8k/5/

Comment: @Vynstus tens de usar `.preventDefault();` e podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/u0ts0w8k/6/ (repara que passei `var err = 0;` para dentro do event handler porque ele precisa de ser 0 cada vez que se tenta fazer submit.

Comment: Legal! Era isso mesmo, obrigado!!